# Excel VBA: String manipulation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The following gives first name, space and last initial. I would like first initial and last name without a space between.

```
Sub FNLI() 

 Dim cell 

 For Each cell In Selection 
 cell.Offset(0, 1) = Mid$(cell.Value2, 1, InStr(cell.Value2, Chr(32)) + 1) 
 Next 

End Sub
```

Here is what it currently does -

```
Data Before:      
Margaret Hicks

After Script:
Margaret H

What I need:
MHicks
```

Comment: 'Excel script' or 'visual basic script' which works in excel but is not limited to excel?

Comment: This question is better suited to Stack Overflow rather than Super User (if you ask this question at SO then pls close this one rather than cross post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
For Each cell In Selection 
cell.Offset(0, 1) = trim(left(cell.Value2,1)&Mid(cell.Value2, InStr(cell.Value2, Char(32)) + 1,len(cell.Value2)-InStr(cell.Value2,Char(32)))) 
Next
```

try #2

cell.Offset(0, 1) = trim(left(cell.Value2,1)&Mid(cell.Value2, search(char(32),cell.Value2) + 1,len(cell.Value2)-search(Char(32),cell.Value2)))

Comment: Thanks.  I get Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: It is just mid not mid$ finger must have slipped

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  I still get the same message.

Comment: try both of the above edits I just made

Comment: I get a Compile Error: Sub or function not defined.  It highlights Char in the first set where is says Search(Char(32)

Comment: Figured it out, should be chr instead of char :)  This is perfect. Just need to get it to lower case and I am in business.  Can you help with that?  Thank you so much!

Comment: there is a function called **lower** so  change the beginning to **lower(trim(** at the very end you need another **)**.

Answer (score 1):

The correct argument is 'Chr' instead of 'Char'

Here is the complete sub compiled and working:

Sub FNLI()

Dim cell

For Each cell In Selection
cell.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(Left(cell.Value2, 1) & Mid(cell.Value2, InStr(cell.Value2, Chr(32)) + 1, Len(cell.Value2) - InStr(cell.Value2, Chr(32))))
Next

End Sub